# google distance api time in minutes

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I use google 's distance matrix api to get the distance and time back like this

```
function calculateDistances() {
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
service.getDistanceMatrix(
{
  origins: [from],
  destinations: [to],
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
  avoidHighways: false,
  avoidTolls: false
}, callback);
}
```

the callback gives me back the time and distance.

The problem i have sometimes if the distance is far the time comes back in hours but i always need minutes for a custom calculation method...

How can i fix this problem...

Comment: just create a method to convert hours to seconds, and then passed it to your custom method

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know whether the time returned is in minutes or hours? Otherwise you could do the obvious and divide the hours by 60!

Comment: @SteveMc it gives something back like 1 hour and 20 minutes... i dont know how to get minutes out of that...

Comment: "something like"? Please show an exact result. Are you saying that it returns a string only?

Comment: @LeeTaylor yeah its a string: it returns  "1 hour 41 min"

Comment: What does it return if there are no hours? "19 min" ?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Yes "19 min" also a string

Comment: Is there something wrong with using the [duration value](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Duration) which is always in seconds and calculating the value in the units you want?

Answer (score 3):

Please check the response object you will have two values text and value. Value property has the duration in seconds.

"duration" : {"text" : "19 hours 9 mins","value" : 68914}

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is really a string extraction problem going from the comments. If the result returned is `"1 hour 41 min"` then you basically want to extract the digits from the string. There's lots of regex that could do that. But you could do it with some straight forward string manipulation.

```
var yourTime = "1 hour 41 min";

var result = yourTime.replace('hour','|');
result = result.replace('min','').trim();
var items = result.split("|");
//you now have an array where the first value is the hours and the second is the minutes
```

There's things to think about, such as trailing and leading spaces, but once the numbers are pulled out it gets down to math.